# Interupt code and wait for user interaction in a loop - React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to implement an "add all" button in my react app. to do that, i pass this function to the onClick method of the button :

```
for (element in elements) {
    await uploadfunction(element)
}

const uploadfunction = async (element) => {
    if (valid) {
        // await performUpload(element)
    }
    else if (duplicate) {
        //show dialog to confirm upload - if confirmed await performUpload(element)
    }
    else {
        // element not valid set state and show failed notification
    }
}

const performUpload = async (element) => {
    // actual upload
    if(successful){
        // set state
    }else{
        // element not successful set state and show failed notification
    }
}
```

the **uploadfunction** can have three different behaviors :

- Add the element to the database and update the state
- Fail to add the element and update the state
- Prompt the user with the React Dialog component to ask for confirmation to add duplicat element and update the state accordingly

My problem now is since i'm using a for loop and despite using Async/await , i can't seem to wait for user interaction in case of the confirmation.

The behavior i currently have :

- The for loop move to the next element no matter what the result
- The Dialog will show only for a second and disappear and doesn't wait for user interaction

Wanted behavior:

- Wait for user interaction (discard/confirm) the Dialog to perform the next action in the loop.

How can i achieve that with React without Redux ?

Comment: What is your desired workflow for the "duplicate" elements?
1. Upload the elements one by one synchronously and prompt the alert only when a duplicate is about to be uploaded?
2. First of all, accept/reject all the duplicates, then asynchronously upload all the elements.

Comment: my desired workflow is the first one you described. If a duplicate detected in the for loop i must not continue until the user confirm/discard the alert/dialog displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a component that might work as an inspiration for you.
You might split it in different components.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    items: [{
      // set default values for all booleans. They will be updated when the upload button is clicked
      isValid: true,
      isDuplicate: false,
      shouldUploadDuplicate: false,
      data: 'element_1',
    }, {
      isValid: true,
      isDuplicate: false,
      shouldUploadDuplicate: false,
      data: 'element_1',
    }, {
      isValid: true,
      isDuplicate: false,
      shouldUploadDuplicate: false,
      data: 'element_2',
    }],
    performUpload: false,
  };

  onUploadButtonClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      items: prevState.items.map((item, index) => ({
        isValid: validationFunction(),
        isDuplicate: prevState.items.slice(0, index).some(i => i.data === item.data),
        shouldUploadDuplicate: false,
        data: item.data
      })),
      performUpload: true,
    }), (nextState) => {
      this.uploadToApi(nextState.items);
    });
  };

  getPromptElement = () => {
    const firstDuplicateItemToPrompt = this.getFirstDuplicateItemToPrompt();
    const firstDuplicateItemIndexToPrompt = this.getFirstDuplicateItemIndexToPrompt();

    return firstDuplicateItemToPrompt ? (
      <MyPrompt
        item={item}
        index={firstDuplicateItemIndexToPrompt}
        onAnswerSelect={this.onPromptAnswered}
      />
    ) : null;
  };

  getFirstDuplicateItemToPrompt = this.state.performUpload
    && !!this.state.items
      .find(i => i.isDuplicate && !i.shouldUploadDuplicate);

  getFirstDuplicateItemIndexToPrompt = this.state.performUpload
    && !!this.state.items
      .findIndex(i => i.isDuplicate && !i.shouldUploadDuplicate);

  onPromptAnswered = (accepted, item, index) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      items: prevState.items
        .map((i, key) => (index === key ? ({
          ...item,
          shouldUploadDuplicate: accepted,
        }) : item)),
      performUpload: accepted, // if at last an item was rejected, then the upload won't be executed
    }));
  };

  uploadToApi = (items) => {
    if (!this.getFirstDuplicateItemToPrompt()) {
      const itemsToUpload = items.filter(i => i.isValid);
      uploadDataToApi(itemsToUpload);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { items } = this.stat;
    const itemElements = items.map((item, key) => (
      <MyItem key={key} {...item} />
    ));

    const promptElement = this.getPromptElement();

    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          {itemElements}
        </div>
        <Button onClick={this.onUploadButtonClick}>Upload</Button>
        {promptElement}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```